# If- Else If statement in vbs scripts

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

I need to know how to make an if - else if statement so that different messages will appear, based on the button (the answer) the user will press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `If`, `ElseIf` and `End If` directives.

```
 If i = 10 Then
     response.write("Just started...!")
 ElseIf i = 11 Then
     response.write("Hungry!")
 End If
```

Comment: Missing space in first line (EndIf -> End If).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner What exactly do you mean?

Comment: i will be able to accept the answer in 5 minutes(idk why)i can't  up-vote yet due to lack of reputation i will when i gain enough though (i think i have 11)

Comment: @aoeu he means that when you wrote ElseIf you should have written Else if with a gap. I think it doesn't matter!