# Else if statement in asp classic not working

Tags: asp-classic

I am having trouble getting this to work. Does anyone have any ideas as I am pulling my hair out.

```
if V30 = 1 then
V40 = "Condition met"
else if V30 = 2 then
V40 = "Condition not met"
else
V40 = ""
end if
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If- Else If statement in vbs scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838608/692942).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it will work

```
If V30 = 1 Then
V40 = "Condition met"
ElseIf V30 = 2 Then
V40 = "Condition not met"
Else
V40 = ""
End If
```